# Is prime algorithm lowest modulo operations

Tags: c#, algorithm

I need to do algorithm for checking if a number is prime with a minimum of modulus checks. I need lowest modulo operations as it possible.

```
   static int counter = 0;

    static bool isPrime(double n)
    {

            if (n <= 1) { return false; }
            if (n <= 3) { return true; }

            counter += 2;
            if (n % 2 == 0 || n % 3 == 0) { return false; }

            for (int i = 5; i * i <= n; i = i + 6)
            {

            counter += 2;
                if (n % i == 0 || n % (i + 2) == 0)
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
```

Comment: `I need lowest modulo operations as it possible.` What makes you think you don't already have that?

Comment: I don't even understand his question

Comment: for example number 10091 in this code has 34 modulo i need 25

Comment: So the question is how can I optimize it to check numbers using the lowest modulo operations

Comment: You need a table of prime numbers. For example, `floor(sqrt(10091))` is 100, and there are exactly 25 prime numbers less than 100. So to minimize the number of modulo operations, you need to first find all of the prime numbers. This can be done with the [sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes).

Comment: Your problem statement is not at all clear.  Are you trying to find primitive roots in particular modulus?  Are you trying to determine whether a number is prime, with a minimum of modulus checks?  Your phrases of the form "10091 - 25 mod" do not seem to mean anything.  Please explain how they relate to your problem.

Comment: @Prune Yes I'm trying to determine whether a number is prime, with a minimum of modulus checks, and for example number 10091 should has no more than 25 modulos checks.

Comment: Very simply, you should check against only primes.  Your algorithm merely excludes composite numbers divisible by 2 or 3 (that's the 6n+1 and 6n-1 iteration you set up).  Earlier comments and links show you how to do this.

Comment: ok now i have code with  6n+1 and 6n-1 should i use Math.Sqrt or not?

Comment: You should not use square roots. The fastest way to check to see if `p > sqrt(n)` is `p * p > n`  But watch out for overflow!

Comment: (1) Yes, keep using sqrt.  (2) You already *have* code for 6n+1 and 6n-1; you've already discovered that it doesn't work.  You need to check against only primes.

Answer (score 2):

The first problem is that the question is tremendously unclear. Let me clarify it.

The algorithm tests for primality by doing a divides-by test as follows:

- Divisibility by 2
- Divisibility by 3
- Now we go into a loop and check 5 and 7, then 11 and 13, then 17 and 19, then 23 and 25, and so on, up to the square root of the number being tested.

This algorithm is clever because it skips checking all even numbers, which were already checked by looking at divisibility by 2, and also skips all divisions by odd numbers divisible by 3, like 9, 15, 21, and so on.

The problem is that it *does* check 25, even though 5 has already been checked.  And it will also check 35, even though 5 and 7 have already been checked.

The *best* you can do with this algorithm is to only do divisibility checks by prime numbers.  That is where these mysterious numbers come from:

> 1009 - 11 mod, 10091 - 25 mod, 100913 - 66 mod

There are 11 prime factors to test less than the square root of 1009.  There are 25 prime factors to test less than the square root of 10091, and so on.

The solution is to precompute a table of small prime numbers, however many you need.  A thousand, say.  You can take as much time as you like, since you'll just do that once and then put that into your program:

```
int[] primes = { 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, ... }
```

and now your algorithm *very simple indeed*:

```
static class Extensions {
  public static bool IsPrime(this int n)
  {
    if (n <= 1) return false;
    foreach(int prime in primes)
    {
        if (prime * (long)prime > (long)n) return true;
        if (n % prime == 0) return false;
    }
    throw new Exception("primes array is too small!");
  }
}
```

**Exercise** why did I cast to long?

**Exercise** how big does the `primes` array have to be in order to ensure that every possible input gives the right answer without throwing?  What if `n` is `long` instead of `int`, how many then?  (Hint: the function that gives you the number of primes less than a number is called the *prime counting function*; do you know anything about it?)

Answer (score 0):

even I don't really understand your question, you might want to take a look at the following [Link](http://www.codinghelmet.com/?path=exercises/prime-testing) from Zoran Horvat.

The site provides a nice analysis how to test is a number a prime number. Besides the provided link, the site contains more content the same topic.

Here is the code snippet (please check the link for further information)

```
static bool IsPrime(int n)
{
    bool result = false;

    if (n <= 3)
    {
        result = true;
    }
        else if (n % 2 != 0 && n % 3 != 0)
    { 
        int k = 5;
        int step = 2;

        while (k * k <= n && n % k != 0)
        {
            k = k + step;
            step = 6 - step;
        }

        if (n == k || n % k != 0)
            result = true;

    }

    return result;    
}
```

Hope this helps. Happy coding!

PS:

1. [Prime Factorization](http://www.codinghelmet.com/?path=exercises/prime-factorization)
2. [Testing if Number is Prime](http://www.codinghelmet.com/?path=exercises/prime-testing)
3. [LINQ Expression to Test If a Number is Prime](http://www.codinghelmet.com/?path=hints/linq-prime-test)
4. [LINQ Expression to Find All Prime Numbers](http://www.codinghelmet.com/?path=hints/linq-all-primes)

Comment: I also wrote something on the mater. It is primarily focussed on how to Multithread such an operation, but it does discuss the 5 or so ways to do this (https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/85fc2406-d2e9-495a-bea7-e516661f8b40/primal-issues-multithreading-lists-in-memory-and-checking-for-prime-number?forum=csharpgeneral). I avoided talking about the more mathy parts (as I do not understand those notations myself fully).

Comment: What you have there is known as [wheel factorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wheel_factorization) using a wheel size of 6. That provides decent optimization for the number of modulo operations, but doesn't provide the absolute minimum that OP is looking for.